# Counting instances of word from a string matching indices

Tags: python

So I have two lists,

`list1 = ['cat', 'hi', 'cat', 'hello']`

`string = "cat hi cat hello"`

I need another list which sets the count of the word to 1 if the word from the string exists in the list and 0 otherwise, but the indices should match and it should not count the instance of the word twice

for example, the result should look like:

`result = [[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0] , [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]]`

This is what I have but it counts other instances of the word too

```
counts = {}
for word in (string.split()):
    if word in list1:
            counts[word] = 1
    else:
        counts[word] = 0
result.append([counts.get(word, 0) for word in list1])
```

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: No, I am doing string preprocessing and this is just an example

Comment: what confuses me a bit is that 'cat' is twice in the list `list1`, how to distinguish the two?

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen Yes, I have the same confusion

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bit vague, but as I understand it: the n<sup>th</sup> word obtained from splitting `string` must equal the n<sup>th</sup> element of `list1` to get a 1 in the n<sup>th</sup> element of the n<sup>th</sup> sublist of `result`:

```
list1 = ['cat', 'hi', 'cat', 'hello']
string = "cat hi cat hello"

s = string.split()
n = len(list1)
assert n == len(s) # must be the same length
result = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)] # all 0's initially
for i in range(n):
    result[i][i] = 1 if s[i] == list1[i] else 0

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

It's the part of the description of the problem "and it should not count the instance of the word twice" that does not make any sense to me based on what I see as your result. But then again you're confused, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create one hot encoding for `string`.

You can use `OneHotEncoder` from `scikit-learn` as below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np


def transform(string, encoder):
    temp_list = np.array(string.split(' ')).reshape((-1,1))
    return encoder.transform(temp_list)


list1 = ['cat', 'hi', 'cat', 'hello']
oe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,handle_unknown='ignore')
oe.fit(np.array(list1).reshape(-1,1))
string = "cat hi cat hello"
transform(string, oe)
```